# UWP Local Toast Notification Does Not Pop Up

Tags: windows, vb.net, uwp, notifications, toast

In a VB.NET UWP app I am writing, I attempt to generate a local toast notification from an in-process background task. However, when I call `show(toast)` to display the notification, it does not display in the corner of my screen and goes directly to action center. Focus assist is not enabled on my machine, so I am unsure if the problem is caused by the termination of the background thread. How do I fix this and allow a local toast notification to pop up?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, a reboot seems to have solved my problem.